# OpenAI moderation continues even though flagged returns error GoFiber (golang, AWS SAM local api gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, go-fiber

I am create an API with GoFiber using AWS API Gateway, and I'm testing locally via `sam local start-api`

The API generates a prompt via OpenAI, and before I do the heavy work of creating the text/image, I run the user input through the moderation API endpoint. If I forcibly return all values from my checker function `ModeratePromptInput`, it will show the error. However, if I check for `err != nil` in the caller it will continue to run the program. How do I fix that?

Here is the caller (the part that matters):

```
// This is the function signature:
// func GenerateOutput(c *fiber.Ctx) (interface{}, error) 

// ....
// Create OpenAI Client for dependency injection
    oClient := openai.NewClient(os.Getenv("OPENAI_SECRET_KEY"))

    // Moderate the input to prevent abuse (exit early if input is abusive)
    err := actions.ModeratePromptInput(c, oClient)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error moderating prompt input: %v", err)
        return nil, c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": "Error within error logic",
        })
    }
    // Code continues here - I want it to stop on error
```

This is the moderation function:

```
func ModeratePromptInput(c *fiber.Ctx, oClient *openai.Client) error {
    promptInput := models.NewOutputRequest{}
    if err := c.BodyParser(&promptInput); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    moderationInput := openai.ModerationRequest{}
    moderationInput.Input = promptInput.UserInput

    res, err := oClient.Moderations(c.Context(), moderationInput)
    if err != nil || res.Results == nil || len(res.Results) == 0 {
        return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": "Could not moderate input",
        })
    }

    if res.Results[0].Flagged {
        return c.Status(403).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error":    "Input is abusive",
            "results:": res.Results,
        })
    }
    return nil
}
```

I've checked myself by stepping through, I've checked with GitHub Copilot, I've checked with ChatGPT, and they all say this is correct. The Marshaled/unmarshaled structs are carrying the data. The request and response objects are correct. However, I'm not getting the flow I'm thinking. Is there something I don't know about go that may be causing this to continue to run?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the following statements return `nil` most of the time:

```golang
return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{
    "error": "Could not moderate input",
})
```

```golang
return c.Status(403).JSON(fiber.Map{
    "error":    "Input is abusive",
    "results:": res.Results,
})
```

It looks like what you want is:

```golang
c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{
    "error": "Could not moderate input",
})
return errors.New("Could not moderate input")
```

But this still does not work because the func `GenerateOutput` will call `c.JSON` again. I don't think that you can write to the response twice.

A possible fix is to modify `ModeratePromptInput` like this:

```golang
var errCouldNotModerate = errors.New("Could not moderate input")

type flaggedError struct {
    results any // I don't know the type of the result
}

func (e *flaggedError) Error() string {
    return "Input is abusive"
}

func ModeratePromptInput(c *fiber.Ctx, oClient *openai.Client) error {
    promptInput := models.NewOutputRequest{}
    if err := c.BodyParser(&promptInput); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    moderationInput := openai.ModerationRequest{}
    moderationInput.Input = promptInput.UserInput

    res, err := oClient.Moderations(c.Context(), moderationInput)
    if err != nil || res.Results == nil || len(res.Results) == 0 {
        if err != nil {
            // at least log the err so that you know what's going on.
        }
        return errCouldNotModerate
    }

    if res.Results[0].Flagged {
        return &flaggedError{
            results: res.Results,
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And modify `GenerateOutput` to construct the response based on the error value.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the interface and err for the future if I wanted to show the weighting of why it was flagged. Is that possible?

Comment: I think so. And in fact that's what I want to suggest you to do. But it involves defining custom error type. Do you want to do that?

Comment: I guess my original thought was to return whatever the callee brings back, as the errors could vary wildly based on factors (failure, unhappy response, some value, etc). This one is pretty simple, but some functions have to interface with multiple structures to get a result, and there could be any number of failures. Do I really have to implement a custom error type to accommodate for every possible permutation of error?

Comment: @JoelHager See  the updated answer which makes `ModeratePromptInput` to return an error. It depends how you want to handle the error. Maybe a simple error returned by `fmt.Errorf` or `errors.New` is enough.

Comment: Anyway, I think you already know that it's wrong to check the error value returned by `c.Status(n).JSON` in your original implementation. It should be changed. How to change it is deeply depends on your business requirement.